# How to show an alert box in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, alert

I want to display an alert box showing a message with PHP.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php  
  header("Location:form.php");

  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert(message successfully sent)';  //not showing an alert box.
  echo '</script>';
  exit;
?>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Why do you want header("Location:form.php") at the top? If you want to  redirect the user to form.php AFTER the alert, you should just redirect the user in the Javascript as such : echo 'location.href="form.php"';

Comment: Look what you have written => echo 'alery(message successfully sent)';  //not showing an alert box.  It should be alery not akery.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

use this code

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

The problem was:

1. you missed `"`
2. It should be `alert` not `alery`

Comment: changed it but still not working.

Comment: @prakash_d22 have you tried to debug it in `firebug` because the code is correct.

Comment: Yes I know the code is fine, but I am not getting the alert box.Is it because of header/exit clause?

Comment: @prakash_d22 may be it was causing problem. Try to comment it and try.

Comment: yes after commenting its working, but I want both .

Comment: @prakash_d22 if you want alert and exit then move the `header` after alert and after that write `exit` OR you can also redirect using `javascript's` window.location.

Comment: How can I print the value of variable in the message?

Comment: @zar Please check this for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331390/creating-a-javascript-alert-with-php-that-has-a-php-variable-inside

Comment: It is better to use type="text/javascript", as language attribute for script tag is not a standard

Comment: how to call PHP via javascript having cors error.. i had added the PHP file in same location as javascript file.

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

Define a funciton:

```
<?php
function phpAlert($msg) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $msg . '")</script>';
}
?>
```

Call it like this:

```
<?php phpAlert(   "Hello world!\\n\\nPHP has got an Alert Box"   );  ?>
```

Comment: this one is better

Answer (score 5):

There is a syntax error (typo):

It's `alert` not `alery`.

Comment: and also this `echo '<script type="text/javascript">';`

Comment: That’s not a syntax error, but a reference error.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "<script>alert('same message');</script>";
```

This may help.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo '<script language="javascript>';
```

Seems like a simple typo. You're missing a double-quote.

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
```

This should do.

Answer (score 2):

change your output from

```
 echo '<script language="javascript>';
```

to

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
```

you forgot double quotes... and use the type tag

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

Answer (score 2):

When I just run this as a page

```
<?php
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
exit;
```

it works fine.

What version of PHP are you running?

Could you try echoing something else after: `$testObject->split_for_sms($Chat);`

Maybe it doesn't get to that part of the code? You could also try these with the other function calls to check where your program stops/is getting to.

Hope you get a bit further with this.

Comment: this code worked for me  echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
    window.location.href='form.php';
    </SCRIPT>");

Comment: So you're echoing the whole string as a whole. Does your whole page + function calls run okay now?

Comment: yes thanks everyone for help..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about php but i belive the problem is from this :

```
enter code here
echo '<script language="javascript>';
echo 'alery("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

Try to change this with :

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

Try to change this with :

```
  echo
  "<script>
  alert('Sent Successfully');
  document.location.href = 'index.php';
  </script>
  ";
```