# Command in PHP equivalent to alert in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, debugging, alert

I use the 'alert' command in javascript's to check values of variables so as to debug my code. but i cant find any such command in PHP which shows a simple popup box like the alert command. im new to PHP.
is there something i dont know?

Ex:

```
$username=$_REQUEST["username"];
$password=$_REQUEST["password"];
```

Here i just want to find out what values are coming in those variables. if it was javascript, i would simply use alert (username) and alert (password). how to do it in php?
thank you.

Comment: There are better ways to debug both PHP and JavaScript - like using an actual debugger.

Comment: I'd recommend you look into firebug and fireftp to debug js and php (both are firefox extensions though they also exist in chrome) you'll find it's much easier to print your variables and call functions there.

Comment: FireBug will not display PHP variables If they are not being printed by PHP in the first place

Comment: i use firebug. as said by hanky panky it doesnt help

Comment: Use an IDE such as netbeans (free) or PhpStorm (not free) that has a PHP debugger built in.

Comment: Hi, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837375/how-to-show-an-alert-box-in-php#answer-13837459 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just echo them

```
echo "Username:".$username;
echo "<br>";
echo "Password:".$password;
```

You can also use [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump)

PHP is a server side language and does not provide client side functionality like JavaScript `alert()`

Comment: but echo is different. it just prints the value. it doesnt pause the code right?
alert command pauses everything and shows the pop up. until we press ok on the popup the remaining code is not executed. this is not the case with 'echo'.

Comment: That is correct. PHP can not do that for you all by itself. By the time you get to see output HTML from a PHP code, PHP has already completed it work and has gone away (Mostly)

Comment: It's pretty common to var_dump() and then exit() when debugging to stop any subsequent redirects, etc.  That's not quite a pause but it lets you inspect a point-in-time.

Comment: Hi, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837375/how-to-show-an-alert-box-in-php#answer-13837459

Answer (score 6):

PHP does not have any function to display a pop-up..

However u can achieve that by writing javascript inside php like this

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Username'".$username.");</script>";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password' ".$password.");</script>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `echo`, `var_dump`, `print_r` or `error_log`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side, not client-side, so to expect it to behave like JavaScript is somewhat strange.

Check out [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead.

If you really want a JS alert, you could always create a PHP function along these lines:

```
function debugAlert($var)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("'.$var.'")'; 
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Then to output your data, just call `debugAlert($username)` etc.

That's a very simplistic version - in reality you'd need to escape quotes in the variable value and also include some logic to handle if the variable is an array or object, but it should get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `print_r($_REQUEST)` . Its displays all the values `array('username'=>'','password'=>'');`

or echo the value echo $username; and echo $password;

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('username and password'+$username+' & '+$password)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```