# Creating a javascript alert with php that has a php variable inside?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, window, alert

I'm making a form that is supposed to create a javascript alert when some fields aren't filled out or filled out properly. *I want to be able to take the error messages I've put in a php variable and display them in the javascript alert window*.

The following code does not work:

```
function died($error) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert('.$error.')</script>';
    die();
}
```

How can I add the string contained in `$error` between the two *"script" strings* so it will output properly as a javascript alert?

Thank you!

Comment: do you want to append the $string and $error variables?

Comment: Why not use javascript to detect if all the forms are filled in?

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up and added an old version of the code I was using to figure out what was wrong. The $string variable is completely unnecessary. I took it out. Thank you!

Comment: You just can do a client checking if you just want to 'alert' the error.. but then again the best way to validate is in the server side.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You only forgot quotations that are required for the JavaScript alert.

If you passed 'hello' to the function, your current code would create alert as:

```
alert(hello)
```

instead of doing:

```
alert("hello")
```

Therefore, change your code to the following (*json_encode()* the string and create a javascript variable out of it):

```php
function died(string $message) {
    if ('' === trim($message)) {
        $message = 'died.';
    }
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var message = <?php echo json_encode($message); ?>;
      alert(message);
    </script>
<?php
    die();
}
```

and you can use your function:

```
died('error on whatever');
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, although I don't really understand why. What if I wanted to add other text in the alert that would be concatenated with the variable? Would I have to do something like this?

    echo '<script>alert('.'Here is some other text!\\n"'.$error.'");</script>';

Comment: as @frankgorman clearly stated, what happens is that, after you concatenated, you missed the quotes inside rendering the error on javascript. If you want to add, just concatenate another string on `$error`. Example: `$error = "Another Line \n" . $error`

Comment: You know you are very new to a language when you look for ways to alert/log variables :) (happens that I came to search for this answer too)

Comment: This displays nothing. As in it does not display the php variable's value for some reason

Comment: Your answer did not work for me, but this did: `echo '<script>alert("' . $str . '");</script>';` [-source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41312694/8840617)

Answer (score 6):

**Display variable php in alert javascript**

```
   <?php 
          function died($error) { ?>

            <script>alert("<?php echo $error; ?>")</script>

    <?php   die(); 
          } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use function follow this:

```
function died($error) {
    echo '<script> alert("'.$error.'")</script>';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{$_SESSION["success"]}');</script>";
 unset($_SESSION["success"]);
?>
```

Use this code it would work correctly

Comment: Ciao, try to add a small explanation. Code-only answer discourages.