# How to echo an alert in PHP a string -- some confusion with single quote and double quotes

Tags: javascript, php

I am completely confused about how to represent a string in an output echo statement to the screen to debug php.

First of all, this actually works perfect for me:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Web Site Under Test -- line 344');</script>";
```

This used double quotes as part of the echo statement, on the outside of the command, so to speak, and single quotes on the alert statement.  And it works.

So how would I send the contents of a string variable in the alert statement?

I think this should work

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$admin_ary -- ' $admin_ary);</script>";
```

Am I right?

---

**Update**

The variable is an array, not a string.
So using `addslashes` does not work

For example, this line:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".addslashes($admin_ary." -- ".$admin_ary)."');</script>"; */
```

produces an alert that says

> Array - Array

Comment: If you think it should work, why not test it? Much quicker than waiting for a "yes" here, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways about it, but variables are passed as values, not actual strings, inside double-quotes. So you're free to do `alert('$admin_ary --  $admin_ary');` (note how the singlequote was moved, as the javascript string needs to be in quotes).

You can also concatenate the string, like this

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$admin_ary." -- ".$admin_ary."');</script>";
```

Or just go out of PHP for the majority of the string, and echo where needed, like this

```
<?php /* Do PHP stuff */ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('<?php echo $admin_ary." -- ".$admin_ary; ?>');</script>
<?php /* More PHP stuff */ ?>
```

If your `$admin_ary` contains singlequotes `'`, it will break the javascript. You can counter this by escaping them, with PHP functions as [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes), which can be done like this

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".addslashes($admin_ary." -- ".$admin_ary)."');</script>";
```

Comment: don't forget to escape the string in the variable or it will break your js code

Comment: Very good post.  I have tried this solution a number of times and, as you have stated, it fails only when there are single quotes as part of the string variable contents.  So I am at a point now investigating how to remove the single quotes with addslashes().

Comment: @xarzu See my revised answer on an example of how to implement `addslashes()`.

Comment: @Tolios, addslashes does not work.  The error is that addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: So you're dealing with arrays, which is very important to know. Dealing with strings and arrays are vastly different. You'll need to show what that array is though, perhaps you want `addslashes($admin_ary[0]." -- ".$admin_ary[1])`, but that all depends on the keys in your array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$wstr = 'www';
w_js_pure_alert($wstr);
function w_js_pure_alert($str)
{
    echo '<script>alert("' . $str . '");</script>';
}

function w_js_pure_console($val)
{
    echo '<script>console.log("' . $val . '");</script>';
}

function w_js_window_location($filename)
{
    echo '<script>window.location="' . $filename . '"</script>';
}
```