# PHP simple test doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I am developing a page in HTML and PHP, but a specific part of PHP doesn't work (the other parts work, including alerts, database connection, etc)... Does anybody have any clue?
Thanks in advance!
Gabriel

```
<form>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="edition_eventname">Nome do Evento</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="edition_eventname" name="edition_eventname" class="form-control">   
                    <?php alert("oi"); ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: change alert to print('<option>oi</option');

Comment: Your question is very vague.  What am I supposed to be looking at and what is your problem?   Why are you alerting with php?

Comment: PHP doesn't have an `alert()` function. You'll need to implement JS for it.

Comment: Do you want to show a javascript popup or just want to display some text on the page?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I sometimes mix up the Javascript and PHP functions. New to PHP...

Comment: so what DO you want? only valid code where you have it is php or script that adds options

Comment: @PeeHaa more specifically, i was using this to debug, since echoing a text wouldn't work inside a select, would it?

Comment: Sure you can echo out data anywhere you like for debugging purposes. Just look at the source and it will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use alert in PHP. That function does not exist.

There are several other functions that print data.

For example:

```
<?php
   echo "my String";
   var_dump( $mixedVar );
   print "hello world";
?>
```

echo and print are not real functions ( language construct ), that's why you can use them with and without parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget this... Not my first time with this problem... Isn't there nothing similar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837375/how-to-show-an-alert-box-in-php

Comment: echo "string"; echo $var;

Comment: @mplungjan Nothing similiar to alert(), just print, echo, var_dump. Depends on what OP wants to do.

Comment: @Doodlebunch var_dump would definitely solve my problem. Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: This is not an answer, it's just a fact. The same fact that PHP "answers" you, when you actually look for your error log. Perhaps you want to visit the OP and install yourself into his computers and always read the error log to him? Just curious  ^^^

Comment: @hakre It acutally is an answer.

Comment: Why don't edit and improve it (at least a little bit). It may be an answer (indeed), but it is not useful for anybody right at the moment.

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap You're right. Is it better now?

Comment: @Doodlebunch Much better! I have reversed my downvote, as it is useful now. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I also just wanted some extra info. I already know these myself

Comment: @mplungjan I thought so. But it was so obvious, I thought "it's not a function" was enough.