# How to show Alert Bootstrap after finish insert or update?

Tags: php, alert

HTML (menu.php)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <?php echo $result; ?>    //result alert
        </div>
    </div>
```

thats code for calling alert bootstrap from process.php.
so when i click button from php.. process.php will check it and return back to menu.php. alert should be show up success or fail.

PHP (process.php)
whole process.php

```
<?php
include('../koneksi.php');
session_start();

$hasilp=MySQL_query ("select * from tb_pin Where id_pin='$_SESSION[id_pin]'");
$datap=mysql_fetch_array ($hasilp); //var

$hasilm=MySQL_query ("select * from tb_menu Where id_menu='$_GET[id_menu]'");
$datam=mysql_fetch_array ($hasilm); // var

$max= "SELECT MAX(jumlah_pemesanan) AS record FROM tb_pemesanan where id_pin='$datap[id_pin]'";
    $query_max =mysql_query($max);
        if ($query_max) {
        $max_r= mysql_fetch_assoc($query_max);
        $max_temp= $max_r['record']+1;
        }

//Cek Result zero
$cek= mysql_query("SELECT id_menu FROM tb_pemesanan_temp WHERE id_menu='$datam[id_menu]' AND id_pin='$datap[id_pin]'");
if (mysql_num_rows($cek) > 0) {

    $hasilj=MySQL_query ("select jumlah from tb_pemesanan_temp Where id_menu='$datam[id_menu]' AND id_pin='$datap[id_pin]'");
    $dataj=mysql_fetch_array ($hasilj); //var

    $newjumlah= $dataj['jumlah'] + 1; //add 1 to jumlah
    $total = $datam['harga_menu'] * $newjumlah; //total

    $update= "UPDATE tb_pemesanan_temp SET id_pin='$datap[id_pin]', id_menu='$datam[id_menu]', 
                jumlah='$newjumlah', total_harga='$total' WHERE id_menu='$datam[id_menu]' AND id_pin='$datap[id_pin]'";
    $query_update =mysql_query($update); //update data
        if ($query_update) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>'; //alert success
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>'; //alert fail
        }

}else{

    $input= "INSERT INTO tb_pemesanan_temp (id_pin, no_meja, jumlah, total_harga, status, keterangan, id_menu, nama_menu, jenis_menu, harga, jumlah_pemesanan) 
        VALUES ('$datap[id_pin]','$datap[no_meja]','1','$datam[harga_menu]','Sedang di proses','-','$datam[id_menu]','$datam[nama_menu]','$datam[jenis_menu]','$datam[harga_menu]','$max_temp')"; //insert data
    $query_input =mysql_query($input);
        if ($query_input) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>'; //alert success
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>'; //alert fail
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: to display the alert, print_r or echo the variable result. If not, it won't display

Comment: already use echo..
but failed..
variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi\user\menu.php

Comment: Update your question with the exact line where you included the echo!

Comment: you sould send the the response again to the menu page, by POST or GET methods, then on menu.php catch the sent data, and assign it to `$result`. you can use ajax, it is the easiest way. Also please show us the whole process so we could help you better

Comment: Did you return the $result variable in your function?

Comment: i dont know how to return it T_T

Comment: i have add the whole process.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show an alert box in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837375/how-to-show-an-alert-box-in-php)